# Execute a query using declared variables

Tags: sql, plsql

I am new to PL / SQL. What should I add to the below block to execute it.? If I run the query individually with values, I am able to create but getting compilation errors when I substitue the datefrom and dateto values. Request help.

```
DECLARE @datefrom DATE;
DECLARE @dateto DATE;
SET @datefrom = '14-Mar-14';
SET @dateto = '15-Mar-14';
select a.* from (select count (distinct CODE) CODES from H_ABC_TABLES WHERE hist_dt between      
@datefrom and @dateto AND HIST_ACTION != 'D') a;
```

Comment: https://www.google.com/#q=how+to+execute+an+oracle+stored+procedure

Comment: This looks like TSQL (Microsoft SQL Server). In what environment are you running this? sqlplus, toad, some other IDE or maybe from a programming language?

Comment: I am running it in SQL Developer

Comment: Did my answer below solve your problem?

Answer (score 0):

You can use either subsitution or bind variables.

**Subsitution:**

```
DEFINE datefrom = '14-Mar-14';
DEFINE dateto = '15-Mar-14';
select a.* from (select count (distinct CODE) CODES from H_ABC_TABLES WHERE hist_dt between      
&datefrom and &dateto AND HIST_ACTION != 'D') a;
UNDEFINE datefrom;
UNDEFINE dateto;
```

This is substituted before the query is run.

**Bind variables:**

```
select a.* from (select count (distinct CODE) CODES from H_ABC_TABLES WHERE hist_dt between      
:datefrom and :dateto AND HIST_ACTION != 'D') a;
```

Fire this in SQL Developer and you should be prompted to fill in the two variables.